# Not loaded javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony

I have code like this in my symfony 2 project.

```
{% extends 'DomestosAdminBundle::layout.html.twig' %}
{% block title %}DomestosAdminBundle:Parent:edit{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
    $(function() {
      var availableTags = {{json|raw}};
      $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
      });
    });
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      function addSchool(value) {
        $.ajax({
          url: '{{path("parent/school/add",{"parent_id": parent.id})}}'
          data: {
            tags: value
          },
          success: function(){ alert("Hello world"); }
          error: function(){ alert("Chyba píčo"); }
        });
      }
    });
  </script>
  {{form_start(form)}}
    <div id="semeno">
      {% for school in parent.school %}
        {{school.name}} <a href="{{path('parent/school/delete', {'parent_id': parent.id, 'school_id' : school.id})}}"><i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-2x"></i></a>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {{form_rest(form)}}
    <input id="tags" name="tags"> &nbsp;<a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="addSchool($('#tags').val()); return false;"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Save</button>
  {{form_end(form)}}
{% endblock %}
```

First function availableTags is working ok, but firebug console throw error that it can't  find addschool action. I know it is wrong placed, using  tag 2 times, but I'm pretty lost in this JS.

Comment: Move `addSchool` function out of `$(function() { .. });` scope. like `<script type="text/javascript">function addSchool(value) { ....}</script>`

Comment: After i did it gave me `SyntaxError: missing } after property list
data: {`, it looks like `<script type="text/javascript">
function addSchool(value) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{path("parent/school/add", {"parent_id": parent.id})}}'
                data: {
                    tags: value
                },
                success: function(){ alert("Hello world"); }
                error: function(){ alert("Chyba píčo"); }
            });
        }
    </script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of visibility of your `addSchool` function. It is declared inside `$(function())` so it is unvisible outside of this block.

Make:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function addSchool(value) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{path("parent/school/add", {"parent_id": parent.id})}}',
                data: {
                    tags: value
                },
                success: function(){ alert("Hello world"); },
                error: function(){ alert("Chyba píčo"); }
            });
        }

</script>
```

of your

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
function addSchool(value) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{path("parent/school/add", {"parent_id": parent.id})}}'
                data: {
                    tags: value
                },
                success: function(){ alert("Hello world"); }
                error: function(){ alert("Chyba píčo"); }
            });
        }
    });
```

It's basically the same code but withouth `$(function())` wrapper which you don't need in this case because you just declare function.

NOTE: declaring functions in global namespace may be considered as a bad practice

Comment: I did copy your code exactly and it throws me: `SyntaxError: missing } after property list
data: {`

Comment: check now, I added comma after url parameter EDIT: and also after success